# exporting runnable jar through eclipse - project using jogl native jars

Tags: eclipse, jar, native, runnable, jogl

i'm using jogl native jars ( as explained -> http://jogamp.org/jogl/doc/userguide/#automatednativelibraryloading ) and i would like to export jar through eclipse as explained -> http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/JogAmp_JAR_File_Handling.
First approach is working, but second isn't and ofcourse i would like to have everything in one jar.

have anyone encountered this problem and is able to share his solution?

im running windows 7 64bit, java 64bit, eclipse 4.3, and latest jogl libriary.

p.s.
i have also tried ant script:

```
    <jar destfile="${dist.dir}/${app.name}-${app.version}.jar">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader"/>
            <attribute name="Rsrc-Main-Class" value="com.home.pso.Uruchom"/>
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="."/>
            <attribute name="Rsrc-Class-Path" value="./ gluegen-rt.jar gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64.jar jogl-all.jar jogl-all-natives-windows-amd64.jar"/>
        </manifest>
        <zipfileset src="jar-in-jar-loader.zip"/>
        <fileset dir="${bin.dir}"/>
        <zipfileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
    </jar>
```

p.s.2 i would like to to do it the easiest way, preferably not using native libraries (.dll, .so), because of name collisions ( diffrent platforms ) and without using any 3-rd party program.

thank you for answers.

**EDIT:**

i forgot to mention, that i want to create runnable jar with my application.

and i am getting following error after running jar, which i created with the second approach:

```
ezekiel@vm-ubuntu:~/Pulpit/workspace/pso/lib$ 
/home/ezekiel/Pulpit/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/bin/java' -jar '/home/ezekiel/Pulpit/pso-1.0.jar' 
Catched URISyntaxException: Expected scheme-specific part at index 5: rsrc:, while    
TempJarCache.bootstrapNativeLib() of null (null + gluegen-rt-natives-linux-amd64.jar)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /home/ezekiel/Pulpit/workspace/pso/lib/libgluegen-rt.so
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1846)
     at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:795)
     at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1061)
     at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibraryInternal(JNILibLoaderBase.java:468)
     at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.access$000(JNILibLoaderBase.java:63)
     at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase$DefaultAction.loadLibrary(JNILibLoaderBase.java:94)
     at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibrary(JNILibLoaderBase.java:332)
     at com.jogamp.common.os.DynamicLibraryBundle$GlueJNILibLoader.loadLibrary(DynamicLibraryBundle.java:390)
     at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform$1.run(Platform.java:210)
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:173)
     at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.<clinit>(GLProfile.java:82)
     at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.<init>(GLCanvas.java:247)
     at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.<init>(GLCanvas.java:197)
     at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.<init>(GLCanvas.java:187)
     at com.home.pso.Uruchom.main(Uruchom.java:74)
     ... 5 more
```

i also tested this under linux ^^

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution
http://forum.jogamp.org/exporting-runnable-jar-through-eclipse-td4030094.html#a4030096
it worked, but then stopped in some release.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Had this issue with Processing 2.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine for you:

1. In eclipse go to File -> New - > Project - > Java Project
2. Create a new folder at the project root called "lib"
3. Paste all the jars into the lib folder you want to include as part of this project's exported jar.
4. Right click on the project and select - > Properties (on the botoom)
5. In the properties dialog select "java build path" from the left (4th from top)
6. In this view, select the "libraries" tab and then click "add jar", in the dialog navigate to your lib folder and shift click all the jars then click okay.
7. No go one tab over to the right "order and export" and select all the jars you just added so that they will be included in the exported jar of your project.
8. Close the project properties dialog by clicking "okay" and rigth click on the project and select "export"
9. Expand the "java" node folder and select "Jar" then click next.
10. Select your project and make sure all others are unchecked.
11. Expand your selected project in the top right tree view and make sure the "lib folder" is checked, otherwise it won't be exported during the build.
12. create a filepath for your exported jar by clicking on "Browse" below " Select export destination"
13. Leave everything else as is, select "Finish" and navigate to your filesystem where you selected the export destination and see that your jar was bult correctly.

Comment: it is not what i had on my mind, but still thanks. i edited my post.